# Remove specific symbol from string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have different string that starts and ends with `{ }` like so `{somestring}`. I want to remove the delimiters from the string so that it shows somestring only. I can't do anything that counts the letters because I don't always know the length of the string.

Maybe this will help. Here is the code, somewhere here I want to delete the delimiters.

```
  private static MvcHtmlString RenderDropDownList(FieldModel model)
    {
        ISerializer serializer = new SerializeJSon();
        var value = "";
        var tb1 = new TagBuilder("select");
        tb1.MergeAttribute("id", model.QuestionId);
        tb1.MergeAttribute("name", model.QuestionId);
        tb1.MergeAttributes(GetHtmlAttributes(model.HtmlAttributes));
        tb1.AddCssClass("form-field");

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        MatchCollection matches = RegexHelper.GetBetweenDelimiter(model.FieldValues, "{", "}");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            var o = match;  //Solution var o = match.toString();
            var tb2 = new TagBuilder("option");
          //Solution  string newString = o.trim(new [] { "{","}"});
            tb2.SetInnerText(o.ToString()); //Solution tb2.SetInnerText(newString);
            sb.Append(tb2.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + "\n");
        }

        tb1.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(tb1.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Comment: The string knows its own length

Comment: Is this possible: `{somestring` or this `{{somestring}}` or even this `{somestring{somestring}`? Do you only want the text from this: `{somestring}`?

Comment: no i only want somestring out of it. Completly without the { and the }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string newString = originalString.Trim(new[] {'{', '}'});
```

Comment: This code removes "{" and "}" chars regardless where tey are, at the start of the string or at the end of it. So "}}}abc{{{" will be transformed into "abc"

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

```
string somestring = somestring.Replace("{","").Replace("}","");
```

Alternatively, you can use [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) and [EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) which will only remove from the beginning and the end of the string, for example:

```
string foo = "{something}";
if (foo.StartsWith("{"))
{
    foo = foo.Remove(0, 1);
}
if (foo.EndsWith("}"))
{
    foo = foo.Remove(foo.Length-1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code removes all "{" and "}" characters including that ones which are within the text: "{a{}b}c}" will be "abc"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It was not explicitly specified that the string will contain `{` within the brackets. However, I have accounted for this in my edit anyway.

Comment: @DanielGustafsson I think a little more input from you is required than just _""cannot resolve replace"_.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what's wrong with this answer so that It can be improved? Thanks. @DanielGustafsson Can you explain the error message further?

Answer (score -1):

You could use replace e.g.

```
string someString = "{somestring}";
string someOtherString = someString.Replace("{","").Replace("}","");
```